# Why do so many books attach such importance to Newton's solution to the problem of orthogonal trajectories?

Tags: biographical-details

The question is about the problem of orthogonal trajectories which newton solved in 1716 (in response to Leibniz's challenge) by deriving the general differential equation which the orthogonal family satisfies. I want to ask what is so important about this question ; it doesn't look hard - seriously, even i can solve it. The differential equation follows imediately from the condition for perpendicularity of two straight lines - that the products of their slopes is -1.

So why so many books attach importance to this solution? i.e i understand the connection with potential theory (field lines and equipotenial lines). Several sources describe Newton's solution to this problem as one of his most ingenius achievements in his later life - a par with his solution to the brachistochrone problem. So what do i miss?

Comment: Compare Newton's solution: [Philosophical Trans, 1716](https://books.google.it/books?id=Vi29eGwVEgYC&pg=PA211) with Jacob Hermann's one : [Acta Erud, 1717; page 349](https://books.google.it/books?id=PSrw2ijLGwIC&pg=PA349). You have to take into account that *analytical geometry* symbols and techbnique were far less developed than modern ones... And see M.Kline's [book](https://books.google.it/books?id=VOcUBvbUXlEC&pg=PA475&lpg=PA475) for a modern overview.

Comment: Newton seems to agree with you: "As this problem, however, is hardly of any use, it has therefore remained neglected and unsolved for many years, in the Acta Eruditorum. And for the same reason I shall not prosecute its solution any further." (from @Mauro's reference)